# How to block referral source on apache with special characters?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, mod-rewrite, spam

I've been getting referral spam on my site. I've tried several options to block it, but it still hits it. I think it has to do with being special characters on the referral?

This is the referral source: с.новым.годом.рф

This is my vhost section:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*C.новым.годом\.рф/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*xn--b1aube0e.xn--c1acygb\.xn--p1ai/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*C.новым.годом\-for\-website\.рф/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*xn--b1aube0e.xn--c1acygb\-for\-website\.xn--p1ai/ [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ – [F,L]
```

I thunk it has to do with the special characters? Or maybe a problem with the regex? Please help.

Comment: Could you provide some examples of the logs?

Comment: The logs were not showing "referral"... and I haven't had a hit from them today.  The referral shows in my Google Analytic.

Comment: It would be useful to show the referral in the logs so you would be sure what Apache is receiving. You could change your logs to use the Combined  Log Format (as described in https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html)